# How to nested method in static method PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods

i want make a static method like this:

```
Class MYClass{
    public static $text = 'apple';
    public static $text2 = ' & banana';

    public static function get($var){

        return static::$var;

    }
    public static function with($var){

        return static::$var;

    }

}
```

if i call :

```
$var = MYClass::get('text');
```

$var will be returned 'apple'

and if i call:

```
$var = MYClass::get('text')->with('text2');
```

$var will be returned 'apple & banana'

how to make that works?

Comment: You can't, unless somehow your static returns an instance, because `->` is an instance operator

Comment: yes with 'return new static()', but how to check if 'static with method' is called?

Comment: Static methods can't be chained (in a nice way) and very much bad practice to return an instance. I would recommend you do as above answer and implement as a singleton.

Comment: MYClass::get('text') returns a string. You are trying 'apple'->with('text2'). If you want chaining, MYClass::get('text') must return an object that has a method with()